# HTML5 video tag doesn't work in FF

Tags: html

On [this site](http://bigfra.me), the video doesn't play in FF. But it does play in Chrome. Is there anything I need to add?

```
<video width="580" height="318" controls poster="link to poster">
    <source src="link to video">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 Video tag. Please update to a <a href="https://www.google.com/chrome/" target="_blank">modern browser</a>.
</video>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your site's source:

```
<source src="/wp-content/themes/bigframe/media/bigframe_reel.mp4">
```

Firefox doesn't support mp4 videos for HTML5 video.

You can add additional sources (WebM, OGG), and fallback to a Flash player. See [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Table) for compatibility.

Comment: Thanks, I added the OGV and it works in FF now. To fallback to a Flash player, do I just add an SWF under the OGV?

Comment: Yep, the text you currently have is the current fallback for browsers that don't understand the video tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by providing video or audio encoded in different formats for different browsers.

```
<video controls>
  <source src="foo.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="foo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
</video>
```